# Copy from Linux command line to Vim

Tags: linux, vim, command-line

I want to copy an alias from my Ubuntu 14.04 command line to my .bashrc file (to make this alias always available).

I have:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~$ alias foo='cd /home/ubuntu/projects/tp; workon env1'
```

I performed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> to copy it then

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~$ vim .bashrc
```

However when I use "p" in Vim I see:

```
"Nothing in register"
```

How can I copy from the command line to my file?

Comment: why not just use redirection? `alias foo >> .bashrc`

Comment: That's a great idea!

Answer (score 2):

Mark the line with the mouse and press the middle mouse button (or right mouse button if you are on Windows using SSH to access the Linux machine) to paste it. Or use "*p to paste from the system clipboard.

Comment: click and drag, to select it

Comment: This works at the command line, but I'm trying to paste into vim

Comment: I'm getting :.,.+352 Nothing in register "

Answer (score 2):

One of two ways:

Go into insert mode in Vim, then enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

The other way is to use the unnamed register (either `*` or `+`) and in command mode you would enter `"+p` or `"*p`. However I found that it just puts empty lines in my file (on [CrunchBang Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CrunchBang_Linux)).

This [link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/In_line_copy_and_paste_to_system_clipboard) also describes a good mapping for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for Vim.
But there are good reasons not to overload <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> on Linux.

Comment: I'm still confused. isn't the unnamed register within vim? I'm copying from the command line before opening vim

Comment: For me I'm getting ":.,.+352 Nothing in register " for both these methods